# python websocket client how to load all responses

Tags: python, websocket

I have a really simple chat server-client (with websockets)

And when I do the following:

```
from websocket import create_connection

client_1 = create_connection("ws://xxx")
client_2 = create_connection("ws://xxx")

client_1.send('hello\n')
client_1.send('world\n')

client_2.recv() # hello\n
client_2.recv() # world\n
```

Is there any way to get all responses? like:

```
client_1.send('hello\n')
client_1.send('world\n')

client_2.recvall() # hello\nworld\n
```

It's for testing purposes, I'm testing my server, and I need to get all received messages for each client

Comment: Why can't you just use loop?

Comment: because if there is no message in the buffer, the recv() will wait eternally

Comment: thank you very much @Amoss, it resolved my question, regards